# Sprite animation works when moving right, but not when moving left

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

I'm making a simple game with Pygame. I have a character sprite which when moving right has all of the animations, but when moving left, the animations are not shown, instead it shows the default standing still animations as the character moves left across the screen. I have been looking at this code for an hour trying to figure out why this is happening and I can't put my finger on why, the moving left part of the code is exactly the same as the moving right part of the code, just loading different images, but it works when moving right and doesn't work when moving left.

Please note in the code below there are rect_stand, rect_right and rect_left, I'm pretty sure the rect_right and rect_left are not actually doing anything because the draw method only uses rect.stand, but I don't think that's the reason it's failing since before I animated walking left, I had walking right with a rect_right and this was fine, it's only in the left direction where it doesn't load the animations.

```
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    sprite_frame = 0

    def __init__(self):
    self.standing_right_frame1 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_standing_facing_right_1.png")
    self.standing_right_frame2 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_standing_facing_right_2.png")
    self.walking_right_frame1 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_1.png")
    self.walking_right_frame2 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_2.png")
    self.walking_right_frame3 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_3.png")
    self.walking_right_frame4 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_4.png")
    self.walking_right_frame5 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_5.png")
    self.walking_right_frame6 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_6.png")
    self.walking_right_frame7 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_7.png")
    self.walking_right_frame8 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_8.png")
    self.walking_right_frame9 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_9.png")
    self.walking_right_frame10 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_right_10.png")
    self.walking_left_frame1 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_1.png")
    self.walking_left_frame2 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_2.png")
    self.walking_left_frame3 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_3.png")
    self.walking_left_frame4 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_4.png")
    self.walking_left_frame5 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_5.png")
    self.walking_left_frame6 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_6.png")
    self.walking_left_frame7 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_7.png")
    self.walking_left_frame8 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_8.png")
    self.walking_left_frame9 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_9.png")
    self.walking_left_frame10 = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\character1_walking_left_10.png")

    self.standing_right = [self.standing_right_frame1, self.standing_right_frame2]
    self.walking_right = [self.walking_right_frame1, self.walking_right_frame2, self.walking_right_frame3, self.walking_right_frame4, self.walking_right_frame5, self.walking_right_frame6, self.walking_right_frame7, self.walking_right_frame8, self.walking_right_frame9, self.walking_right_frame10]
    self.walking_left = [self.walking_left_frame1, self.walking_left_frame2, self.walking_left_frame3, self.walking_left_frame4, self.walking_left_frame5, self.walking_left_frame6, self.walking_left_frame7, self.walking_left_frame8, self.walking_left_frame9, self.walking_left_frame10]
    self.character_sprite = self.standing_right
    self.rect_stand = self.standing_right_frame1.get_rect()
    self.rect_right = self.walking_right_frame1.get_rect()
    self.rect_left = self.walking_left_frame1.get_rect()
    self.rect_stand.center = (200, 300)

    def character_standing_still(self):
        sprite_index = self.sprite_frame // 15
        if sprite_index >= len(self.standing_right):
            self.sprite_frame = 0
            sprite_index = 0
        self.character_sprite = self.standing_right[sprite_index]
        self.sprite_frame = self.sprite_frame + 1


    def character_walking(self, direction = "Standing"):
        if direction == "Left":
            sprite_index = self.sprite_frame // 15
            self.rect_stand.move_ip(-5, 0)
            if sprite_index >= len(self.walking_left):
                self.sprite_frame = 0
                sprite_index = 0
            self.character_sprite = self.walking_left[sprite_index]
            self.sprite_frame = self.sprite_frame + 1
        elif direction == "Right":
            sprite_index = self.sprite_frame // 15
            self.rect_stand.move_ip(5, 0)
            if sprite_index >= len(self.walking_right):
                self.sprite_frame = 0
                sprite_index = 0
            self.character_sprite = self.walking_right[sprite_index]
            self.sprite_frame = self.sprite_frame + 1
        else:
            self.character_standing_still()


    def update(self):
        pressed_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.rect_stand.left > 0:
            if pressed_key[K_LEFT]:
                self.character_walking("Left")
            else:
                self.character_standing_still()
        else:
            self.character_standing_still()
        if self.rect_stand.right < screen_width:
            if pressed_key[K_RIGHT]:
                self.character_walking("Right")
            else:
                self.character_standing_still()
        else:
            self.character_standing_still()


    def draw(self, display):
        self.game_screen = display
        self.game_screen.blit(self.character_sprite, self.rect_stand)  


pygame.init()
character = Character()

while game_running:

    game_clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False

    game_screen.fill(color_white)
    character.update()
    character.draw(game_screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Why is it checking 3x positions before checking the key-press?   Is the `else:` clause of the K_LEFT movement supposed to be handling `standing_right`?  I expected to see `standing_left`.  Ah, and it should check left *else* check right... say no keys are pressed, and the player is not on the side of the window.  Follow the code path in your head ... it *always* exits through the `else:` part of K_RIGHT.

Comment: standing_right is the rest animation when the character is not moving (I have not yet added a standing left). So if the left key is pressed, do the left animation, else "standing_right" aka not moving animation. As for the 3 positions, I have to clean that up, only rect_stand is actually useful to the code, the other two need to be removed.

Comment: @Kingsley can you explain why it is always exits at the K_RIGHT else part? I'm not understanding why. Because when the left key is pressed, it still runs the self.rect_stand.move_ip(-5, 0) part of the code inside of the K_LEFT part of the if statement since the character's position moves, but it doesn't show the animation like it does when the character moves right.

Comment: IF you modify the `character_walking()` and `character_standing_still()` functions to simply do `print("left")`, `print("right")`, and `print("stand")` when it changes, you'll see that it's *always* calling `character_standing_still()` immediately after moving left... even with the `K_LEFT` key held in.  This is because the `update()` is not checking for the key-press first.  As I said in my answer, even if you're pressing K_LEFT (and holding it in), `update()` *always* executes the last line in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: *Possibly* multiple issues.

Firstly, the `K_LEFT` code is using `self.standing_right` for the sprite image.  (It's not clear if this is correct, but it looks wrong).

Secondly, imagine no keys are pressed, and follow the `update()` function in your imagination.  It logically reduces down to something like:

```
def update(self):
    if ( not-against-window-edge ):

        if ( left is pressed ):
            paint left-walking-image
        else:
            paint right-standing-image  # <<-- Always ends up here on no-keys

        if ( right is pressed ):
            paint right-walking-image
        else:
            paint right-standing-image  # <<-- Always ends up here on no-keys
```

So if no keys are pressed, it's always showing the right-standing sprite as a last-step.  The code needs to remember the previously faced direction.

So changing the second `if` to `elif`, remembering the direction, and some re-arranging:

```
def update(self):
    pressed_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if pressed_key[K_LEFT]:
        self.facing = 'left'   # Turn Left
        sprite_index = self.sprite_frame // 8
        if self.rect_stand.left > 0 or self.rect_right.left > 0 or self.rect_left.left > 0:
            self.rect_stand.move_ip(-5, 0)
            self.rect_left.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if sprite_index >= len(self.walking_left):
            self.sprite_frame = 0
            sprite_index = 0
        self.character_sprite = self.walking_left[sprite_index]
        self.sprite_frame = self.sprite_frame + 1

    elif pressed_key[K_RIGHT]: 
        self.facing = 'right'
        sprite_index = self.sprite_frame // 8
        if self.rect_stand.right < screen_width or self.rect_right.right < screen_width or self.rect_left.right < screen_width:
            self.rect_stand.move_ip(5, 0)
            self.rect_right.move_ip(5, 0)
        if sprite_index >= len(self.walking_right):
            self.sprite_frame = 0
            sprite_index = 0
        self.character_sprite = self.walking_right[sprite_index]
        self.sprite_frame = self.sprite_frame + 1

    else:   
        # Neither left/right pressed, show stopped sprite
        sprite_index = self.sprite_frame // 15
        if ( self.facing == 'left' ):
            if sprite_index >= len(self.standing_right):  # TODO: left
                self.sprite_frame = 0
                sprite_index = 0
            self.character_sprite = self.standing_right[sprite_index]  # TODO: left
        elif ( self.facing == 'right' ):
            if sprite_index >= len(self.standing_right):
                self.sprite_frame = 0
                sprite_index = 0
            self.character_sprite = self.standing_right[sprite_index]
        self.sprite_frame = self.sprite_frame + 1
```

Not forgetting to add 'self.direction' to the `__init__()`.

It might be better to simply store a reference to the animation frames currently being used.  Say you have:

```
class Player():
    def __init__( self, blah ):
        self.left_animation_sprites  = [ ... ]
        self.right_animation_sprites =  [ ... ]
        self.current_animation = self.right_animation_sprites
```

Then when you change directions, it's just a matter of referring to the "other" set of animations.

```
    def turnLeft( self ):
        if ( self.direction != 'left' ):
            self.direction = 'left' 
            self.current_animation = self.left_animation_sprites
            self.sprite_frame = 0
```

So now when you're animating in update, it's always looping through `self.current_animation`.  This way your update code doesn't need to know which direction the player is facing.

**EDIT**

Essentially the updated code still has the same problem, and that is that the `update()` function will always execute `self.character_standing_still()` (the one on the last line of the function) when heading Left.

I can't be sure, but until I modified the code, I couldn't get the frame-indexing to work correctly either.  But that was probably me.  Anyway I removed the uses of a temporary `sprite_index` in lieu of just using the length of the animation list.

The code is not storing the direction of travel, so can't paint the correct "still" image left/right.  It always uses right.  This is also a minor part of the problem.

Here's a fixed version (but still doesn't remember the direction):

```
import pygame

screen_width  = 500
screen_height = 500
game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( screen_width, screen_height ) )

color_white = ( 200, 200, 200 )

class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self):
        self.sprite_frame = 0
        self.standing_right_frame1 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_standing_facing_right_01.png")
        self.standing_right_frame2 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_standing_facing_right_01.png")
        self.standing_left_frame1 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_standing_facing_left_01.png")
        self.standing_left_frame2 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_standing_facing_left_01.png")
        self.walking_right_frame1 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_01.png")
        self.walking_right_frame2 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_02.png")
        self.walking_right_frame3 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_03.png")
        self.walking_right_frame4 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_04.png")
        self.walking_right_frame5 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_05.png")
        self.walking_right_frame6 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_06.png")
        self.walking_right_frame7 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_07.png")
        self.walking_right_frame8 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_08.png")
        self.walking_right_frame9 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_09.png")
        self.walking_right_frame10 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_right_10.png")
        self.walking_left_frame1 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_01.png")
        self.walking_left_frame2 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_02.png")
        self.walking_left_frame3 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_03.png")
        self.walking_left_frame4 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_04.png")
        self.walking_left_frame5 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_05.png")
        self.walking_left_frame6 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_06.png")
        self.walking_left_frame7 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_07.png")
        self.walking_left_frame8 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_08.png")
        self.walking_left_frame9 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_09.png")
        self.walking_left_frame10 = pygame.image.load("images/character1_walking_left_10.png")

        self.standing_right = [self.standing_right_frame1, self.standing_right_frame2]
        self.walking_right = [self.walking_right_frame1, self.walking_right_frame2, self.walking_right_frame3, self.walking_right_frame4, self.walking_right_frame5, self.walking_right_frame6, self.walking_right_frame7, self.walking_right_frame8, self.walking_right_frame9, self.walking_right_frame10]
        self.walking_left = [self.walking_left_frame1, self.walking_left_frame2, self.walking_left_frame3, self.walking_left_frame4, self.walking_left_frame5, self.walking_left_frame6, self.walking_left_frame7, self.walking_left_frame8, self.walking_left_frame9, self.walking_left_frame10]
        self.character_sprite = self.standing_right
        self.rect_stand = self.standing_right_frame1.get_rect()
        self.rect_right = self.walking_right_frame1.get_rect()
        self.rect_left = self.walking_left_frame1.get_rect()
        self.rect_stand.center = (200, 300)

    def character_standing_still(self):
        if self.sprite_frame >= len(self.standing_right):
            self.sprite_frame = 0
        self.character_sprite = self.standing_right[self.sprite_frame]
        self.sprite_frame = self.sprite_frame + 1


    def character_walking(self, direction = "Standing"):

        if direction == "Left":
            print( "left" )
            if self.rect_stand.left > 0:
                self.rect_stand.move_ip(-5, 0)
            if self.sprite_frame >= len(self.walking_left):
                self.sprite_frame = 0
            self.character_sprite = self.walking_left[self.sprite_frame]
            self.sprite_frame = self.sprite_frame + 1

        elif direction == "Right":
            if self.rect_stand.right < screen_width:
                self.rect_stand.move_ip(5, 0)
            if self.sprite_frame >= len(self.walking_right):
                self.sprite_frame = 0
            self.character_sprite = self.walking_right[self.sprite_frame]
            self.sprite_frame = self.sprite_frame + 1
        else:
            self.character_standing_still()


    def update(self):
        pressed_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed_key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.character_walking("Left")
        elif pressed_key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.character_walking("Right")
        else:
            self.character_standing_still()


    def draw(self, display):
        self.game_screen = display
        self.game_screen.blit(self.character_sprite, self.rect_stand)  


pygame.init()
character = Character()

game_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_running = True
while game_running:


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False

    game_screen.fill(color_white)
    character.update()
    character.draw(game_screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    game_clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and making the character face the direction they last moved in was what I was going to try to figure out next after solving this issue so thank you for that. What I'm confused about is that my character does move left when the key is pressed but does not do the walking left animation. So basically: Does character move right when right is pressed? Yes. Does it show the right walking animation? Yes. Does the character move left when left is pressed? Yes. Does it show the left walking animation? No. This is the issue.

Comment: @maxpower8888 - Are you sure the images are correct?  At loading time?  (you're not loading the right-animation into the left-animation list?)  None of that's in the question code.

Comment: I checked the images and they are the correct files. I left them out of the code previously to save space, I have updated the code with the files of the images.

Comment: BTW I also updated the code and cleaned it up, it looks different than the last time you saw it.